# How to create charts with custom filters about sensitive data using JS without using external APIs?

Tags: 2010, caml-query, chart

I need to create charts out of business data which comes out of SharePoint lists in SharePoint 2010. The solution needs the ability to easily filter the data by custom queries, just like the SPJS Charts for SharePoint (by Alexander Bautz) library has. ([example configuration of a year-filter](http://sharepointjavascript.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/filtersetup_2.png), [resulting year-filter](http://sharepointjavascript.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/linechart-focustarget-category.png))

Unfortunately this library uses the Google Chart Api which is problematically for companies as they don't want their data to be exposed to google.

Are there any JS libraries which meet those needs?

Comment: Are you looking for any third party solutions?

Comment: @sharmila: I consider JS libraries as 3rd party solutions - so yes. If you mean SharePoint solutions then I have to deny, as it should not affect the farm.

Comment: I am not quiet sure about the JS libraries which would accomplish your requirement. But if you can use silverlight charts then I would recommend Visifire for SharePoint. Its a webpart to create charts and customize charts like filerting,grouping without writing any code. Check out http://www.visifire.com/sharepoint_chart_webpart.php

Answer (score 1):

Collabion supports Web Part Connections, so you can filter data based on the query string.  You'll need to use the Query String filter web part and connect it to Collabion Charts, it's fairly simple. see their [docs](http://docs.collabion.com/charts/2.0/contents/user_interaction/web_part_connection.html) for more info. 
Nevron, has [something similar](http://helpdotnetvision.nevron.com/Nevron.UI.WebForm.Controls~Nevron.UI.WebForm.Controls.NPermanentSessionStateManager~QueryStringField.html) too. 
Hope this helps.